# Как добавить библиотеку с гитхаба в существующий проект?

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! Возникла необходимость добавить сею библиотеку https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView в уже существующий проект. Как это сделать? Из ридми, увы, мало что понял. Я пользуюсь Android Studio 0.8.6b

Comment: Update:
Я закинул файлы во вновь созданную папку libraries в корне. Добавил строку в Settings.gradle

    include ':libraries:AndroidHorizontalListView'

добавил эту библиотеку в File>Project Structure>Dependencies. И у меня появилась ошибка 

    Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Кто виноват и что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbyqaCKYvfM

Comment: @katso у меня возникла проблема (в апдейт вопроса добавил). А по поводу гугления - на этой работе youtube заблокирован, а в тексте не нашел на русском..